# How to Screen Capture while in Cmd+Tab

Tags: macos, screen-capture

I ran into a rare situation - I want to snag a picture of my screen while using `cmd+tab` to show people how I navigate around in this how-to post.

The regular `cmd+shift+3` or `4` didn't do anything. Thoughts on getting around it?

I run lion 10.8.3 on a MBA.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
screencapture -T 5 /tmp/screencapture.png # 5 second delay
screencapture -T 5 -cC # -c copies to clipboard, -C includes a cursor
screencapture -T 5 -ic # -i (interactive mode) is like shift-command-4
```

I also use a function like this:

```
screencaps() {
  while :; do
    screencapture -C ~/Desktop/$(date +%y%m%d%H%M%S).png
    sleep ${1-1}
  done
}
```

Comment: I'm noticing a bit of a trend here ;)

Answer (score 10):

Open Grab, go to Capture -> Timed Screen, then make sure the cmd+tab module is up on the screen when the timer runs out. Then open in Preview and crop as desired.